# How to align equation numbers in table with equations outside it automatically?

Tags: tables, equations

For the example below, is there any way to align the equation numner (1) with equation number (2) and (3) automatically? Adjusting the parameter in `\parbox` manually every time is annoying.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% packages used in my real .tex script
\usepackage[fontset=adobe]{ctex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./chapter-01-img/} }

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    p(x\in(a, b)) = \int^b_ap(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
%
%some text...
%
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textbf{discrete random variable} & \parbox{6.1cm}{\begin{equation}\mathbb{E}[f]=\sum_xf(x)p(x)\end{equation}} \\
    \textbf{continuous random variable} & \parbox{6.1cm}{\begin{equation}\mathbb{E}[f]=\int f(x)p(x)\mathrm{d}x\end{equation}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and here is my `ctex-fontset-adobe.def`:

```
%%
%% This is file `ctex-fontset-adobe.def',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% ctex.dtx  (with options: `fontset,adobe')
%% 
%%     Copyright (C) 2003--2017
%%     CTEX.ORG and any individual authors listed in the documentation.
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% 
%%     This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%%     conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
%%     version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
%%     version. This version of this license is in
%%        http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/lppl-1-3c.txt
%%     and the latest version of this license is in
%%        http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%%     and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of
%%     LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%% 
%%     This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%% 
%%     The Current Maintainers of this work are Leo Liu, Qing Lee and Liam Huang.
%% 
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% 
\GetIdInfo$Id: ctex.dtx c498d8c 2017-04-01 21:33:50 +0800 Qing Lee <sobenlee@gmail.com> $
  {Adobe fonts definition (CTEX)}
\ProvidesExplFile{ctex-fontset-adobe.def}
  {\ExplFileDate}{2.4.9}{\ExplFileDescription}
\sys_if_engine_pdftex:TF
  {
    \sys_if_output_pdf:TF
      { \ctex_fontset_error:n { adobe } }
      {
        \ctex_zhmap_case:nnn
          {
            \setCJKmainfont
              [
                      cmap = UniGB-UTF16-H ,
                  BoldFont = Source Han Sans SC Bold,
                ItalicFont = AdobeKaitiStd-Regular.otf
              ] { Source Han Sans SC Regular }
            \setCJKsansfont [cmap = UniGB-UTF16-H] { Source Han Sans SC Regular }
            \setCJKmonofont [ cmap = UniGB-UTF16-H ] { Source Han Sans HW SC Regular }
            \setCJKfamilyfont { zhsong }
              [ cmap = UniGB-UTF16-H ] { Source Han Serif CN Regular }
            \setCJKfamilyfont { zhhei }
              [ cmap = UniGB-UTF16-H ] { Source Han Sans SC Regular }
            \setCJKfamilyfont { zhkai }
              [ cmap = UniGB-UTF16-H ] { AdobeKaitiStd-Regular.otf }
            \setCJKfamilyfont { zhfs }
              [ cmap = UniGB-UTF16-H ] { AdobeFangsongStd-Regular.otf }
            \ctex_punct_set:n { adobe }
            \ctex_punct_map_family:nn { \CJKrmdefault } { zhsong }
            \ctex_punct_map_family:nn { \CJKsfdefault } { zhhei }
            \ctex_punct_map_family:nn { \CJKttdefault } { zhfs }
            \ctex_punct_map_itshape:nn { \CJKrmdefault } { zhkai }
            \ctex_punct_map_bfseries:nn { \CJKrmdefault } { zhhei }
          }
          {
            \ctex_load_zhmap:nnnn { rm } { zhhei } { zhfs } { zhadobefonts }
            \ctex_punct_set:n { adobe }
            \ctex_punct_map_family:nn { \CJKrmdefault } { zhsong }
            \ctex_punct_map_bfseries:nn { \CJKrmdefault } { zhhei }
            \ctex_punct_map_itshape:nn { \CJKrmdefault } { zhkai }
          }
          { \ctex_fontset_error:n { adobe } }
      }
  }
  {
    \setCJKmainfont
      [
        BoldFont = SourceHanSerifCN-Bold,
%        ItalicFont = AdobeKaitiStd-Regular.otf
      ] { Source~Han~Serif~CN }
    \setCJKsansfont { Source~Han~Sans~SC~Regular }
    \setCJKmonofont { Source~Han~Sans~HW~SC~Regular }
    \setCJKfamilyfont { zhsong } { Source~Han~Serif~CN }
    \setCJKfamilyfont { zhhei }  { Source~Han~Sans~SC~Regular }
    \setCJKfamilyfont { zhfs }   { AdobeFangsongStd-Regular }
    \setCJKfamilyfont { zhkai }  { AdobeKaitiStd-Regular }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \songti   { } { \CJKfamily { zhsong } }
\NewDocumentCommand \heiti    { } { \CJKfamily { zhhei } }
\NewDocumentCommand \fangsong { } { \CJKfamily { zhfs } }
\NewDocumentCommand \kaishu   { } { \CJKfamily { zhkai } }
%% 
%%
%% End of file `ctex-fontset-adobe.def'.
```

Comment: Please complete this to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  My guess is that your  equation numbers in the table are sticking out in to the margin, but I can't test that without more code.

Comment: i cant reprosuce your problem, however i haven't any clue about used `\documentclass{...}`, loaded packages etc. please extend your code snippet in small complete document

Comment: No blank line should precede a display and one *can* follow it, but only if the text starts a new paragraph.

Comment: I update my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually need a tabular, just use what is offered by math packages for this. `alignat` from `amsmath` packages is exactly used for these cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    p(x\in(a, b)) = \int^b_ap(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
%
some text...
%
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \textbf{discrete random variable}   &            &&\mathbb{E}[f]=\sum_xf(x)p(x)   \\
  \textbf{continuous random variable} & \quad\quad &&\mathbb{E}[f]=\int f(x)p(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: No blank line should precede a display and one *can* follow it, but only if the text starts a new paragraph.

Comment: Sure, thank you, I just kept the lines of the OP intact.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to hack a displayed equation mode into the tabular environment seems like a distinctly unsatisfactory solution to me. Why don't you use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package instead?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    p(x\in(a, b)) = \int^b_ap(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

some text...

\begin{align}
\textbf{discrete random variable} \qquad & \mathbb{E}[f]=\sum_xf(x)p(x) \\
\textbf{continuous random variable} \qquad & \mathbb{E}[f]=\int f(x)p(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you forgot on  `\begin{document}` ...

Comment: I did indeed! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: No blank line should precede a display and one *can* follow it, but only if the text starts a new paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

Using `flalign` is another solution. I ook the opportunity to improve the spacing of the differential symbol in the integral, through a dedicated command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    p(x\in(a, b)) = \int^b_ap(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
%
some text...
%
\begin{flalign}
  \textbf{discrete random variable} & &&\mathbb{E}[f]=\sum_xf(x)p(x)\\
  \textbf{continuous random variable} & &&\mathbb{E}[f]=\int f(x)p(x)\dd x & &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]